# SQL Timestamps - calculating SLA

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have several tickets and want to provide a reporting based on Service Level Agreements with PHP.

A new ticket might have the status 'new' with a certain timestamp and after some time the status 'closed' with a certain timestamp.

The difference between those two timestamps should be calculated, however only working hours from monday to friday (8am to 4.30 pm) should be relevant. So if the ticket is created at 4pm on Friday and closed at 9am on the following Monday, the time elapsed should be 1.5 hours.

Anyone an idea how to get the excepted results out of the database?

The database is a mysql database, the bugtracking system is the open source BTS Mantis Bugtracker.

A pretty simple part of the database tables:

table bug:

ID | status | date_created (TIMESTAMP) | last_modified (TIMESTAMP)

table history

ID | bug_id (ref bug) | status_old | status_new | date_modified (TIMESTAMP)

My query in PHP: 
Gets all the bugs that were set to status 30 in a certain timeframe. 
For the highest SLA level this fram is between 0 and 2 hours. 
Query works fine - but the timeframe does not care about working hours...

SELECT bug.id as ID 
    FROM mantis_bug_table as bug, mantis_bug_history_table as history
    WHERE history.new_status = 30 and history.bug_id = bug.id 
    AND (history.date_modified - bug.date_submitted) < '{$timeframe_end}' 
    AND (history.date_modified - bug.date_submitted) > '{$timeframe_start}'";

Comment: Seems clear enough to me. Calculate working time elapsed between two instants.

Comment: @Ben - then tell me, what has been tried ? Which database and version is being used ? How are the tables defined ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, it **can** "be reasonably answered in it's current form", so it doesn't qualify for "not a real question".

Comment: The database is a mySQL database, the system is Mantis BT ticket system. The structure is quite simple, as an example you can imagine a design like the follwing: table bug: ID, date_created (TIMESTAMP), date_modified (TIMESTAMP) - and a table histroy: ID, bug_id, date_modified (TIMESTAMP), field (e.g. status), old_value, new_value

Answer (score 2):

You need a table showing all working periods, e.g.:

```
create table WorkingPeriod (
    dtPeriodStart datetime primary key,
    dtPeriodEnd datetime,
    unique(dtPeriodEnd, dtPeriodStart)
)
```

You must ensure working periods do not overlap.

Then you can calculate the working time. It will be the number of whole periods, plus the partial period at the beginning and end. This example should work on Microsoft T-SQL, but you may have to use TIMESTAMPDIFF for MySQL or make another simple change.

```
create function dbo.GetWorkingTimeSeconds(@dtStart, @dtEnd)
returns int 
as
begin
   declare @a int
   -- Add up all the WorkingPeriods between @dtStart and @dtEnd
   -- SUM adds them all up
   select @a = SUM(
       -- Get the number of seconds between the start of the period and the end
       datediff(
           -- We want the difference in seconds
           second,

           -- BUT if @dtStart is after the start of the period, 
           --  use @dtStart instead - so we don't count the part
           -- of the period before @dtStart
           case 
           when @dtStart < dtPeriodStart then dtPeriodStart
           else @dtStart 
           end,

           -- If @dtEnd is BEFORE the end of the period, 
           -- use @dtEnd instead, so we don't count the part of the period after @dtEnd
           case
           when @dtEnd > dtPeriodEnd then dtPeriodEnd
           else @dtEnd
           end
       )
    )
    from
        WorkingPeriods 
        -- Only include periods which overlap our time range
        where dtPeriodEnd >= @dtStart and dtPeriodStart < @dtEnd

    -- return the value
    Return @a
  end
```

Why use a table?

- You can take account of public holidays, by not including them
- If the working day changes in future, the table can change for future dates, leaving past dates untouched, so working time calculations for past events continue to be correct.
- You can even exclude lunchtimes, have half-days at weekends, or anything else you want.

Comment: I'm not sure, whether I really understood that concept. I create a table with WorkingPeriods (start & end time) - but what does the function actually do?

Comment: johaaachim this solution counts the # of seconds for a given timespan (e.g. @dtStart through @dtEnd) that falls within your predefined table of working periods, which you'd need to populate before executing this function. Great job, @Ben!